# Synchronized method() running only 1 thread till end from a poll of several

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This is a project I'm trying to do for University.

I'm making an app using sockets to connect several Clients to a Server.
When I get a new connection a new instance of `ServerHandler` is called that listens to the port for requests from the Client.

This is my ServerHandler class

```
public class ServerHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Server server;
    ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    ArrayList<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();
    ArrayList<News> filteredNews = new ArrayList<>();
    private int iterator = 0;
    private boolean available = true;
    private boolean finished = false;

    public ServerHandler(Socket clientSocket, Server server) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.server = server;
        this.news = server.getListNews();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for input");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String str = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            manageMessages();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                       
                    }

                    private void manageMessages() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                        System.out.println("Button Search.");
                        launchThreads(str);
                        for(Thread t : threads) {
                            t.join();
                        }
                        filteredNews.sort(null);
                        System.out.println("News have been filtered and sorted.");
                        System.out.println("Sending info to Client.");
                        sendtoClient();
                        System.out.println("Sent info to Client.");             
                    }
                }).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Socket closed" + e);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

When I get a request I launch a new Thread responsible of returning something to the Client.

My problem comes from the `launchThreads(String str)` method.
This method is meant to create and add 10 threads to an Array of Threads.
Each Thread then is going to run through the same `ArrayList` of News in search of a word (`String str`, sent by the Client).

All threads are supposed to share the work, that is searching for the `String str` through every single News in the shared `ArrayList<News>`.

```
private void launchThreads(String str) {
    System.out.println("Lauching threads");
    filteredNews.clear();
    threads.clear();
    finished = false;
    available = true;
    iterator = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){try {
            queueThreads(str);
            filterNews(str);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}));
        threads.get(i).start();
    }
    System.out.println("Launched threads: " + threads.size());
}

private synchronized void queueThreads(String str) throws InterruptedException {
    while(!available && !finished) {
        System.out.println("Waiting.");
        wait();
    }
    System.out.println("Gone through.");
    available = false;  
}

private synchronized void filterNews(String str) throws InterruptedException {
    int contador = 0;
    if(iterator < news.size()) {
        String temp = news.get(iterator).getTitle() + " " + news.get(iterator).getBody();
        String[] tempArray = temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");
        for(String word : tempArray) {
            if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        if(contador > 0) {
            News n = new News(news.get(iterator).getTitle(),news.get(iterator).getBody(), contador);
            n.setTitle(contador + " - " + n.getTitle());
            System.out.println(news.get(iterator).toString());
            filteredNews.add(n);
        }
        iterator++;
    }else {
        finished = true;
    }
    available = true;
    notifyAll();
    queueThreads(str);}
```

What I'm getting is that only 1 Thread runs the whole search while the other ones just stay waiting until I change the finished flag to `'true'`, that is set when the search ends.

I would love to get some help on how can I launch several threads to run through the array sharing work between them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using raw threads is somewhat of an anti-pattern. Use [`ExecutorService`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), in particular the [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) provides load balancing between worker threads.

Comment: The objective is to implement synchronization on the most basic level using only synchronized methods, waits() and notify()

Comment: So it's homework? If so, you may want to include this information in your question.